# Стоит ли изменять значения primary key?

Tags: sql, база-данных

Допустим, у меня есть таблица, которая хранит в себе список разделов сайта. Если же нужно изменить порядок этих разделов при выводе в меню (например, из "главная | контакты | новости" сделать "главная | новости | контакты"), то стоит ли изменять значения Primary key или же это является плохой практикой и лучше создать новое поле и менять его значения?

Comment: а зачем менять статьи метами? и главное, что за места? где эти места?

Comment: Primary key неприкосновенен. Для определения их порядка придумывайте другие критерии.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman под "менять статьи местами" я имел ввиду "изменить их порядок"

Comment: @СемушинСергей порядок где?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman, очевидно, порядок при выводе. Да, со статьями не очень пример был, сейчас отредактирую вопрос)

Comment: @СемушинСергей совершенно не очевидно

Comment: Тут редактировать нечего. и так ясно - примари менять нельзя и порядок сортировки от него точно зависеть не должен. нужна настраиваемая сортировка - делаете отдельное поле. причем желательно не 1,2,3 а то вставлять в середину не удобно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как уже подсказали в комментариях,
"Primary key неприкосновенен" (c) [@PinkTux](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/194908/pinktux)
и
"примари менять нельзя и порядок сортировки от него точно зависеть не должен" (c) [@Mike](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/194569/mike)

Спасибо за ответы!

Comment: Надо понять что такое Primary Key. Менять его можно, но очень не выгодно. Обычно на него ссылается множество других записей их разных таблиц. Если его изменить, то надо менять по всей базе. Но если вдруг таблица без связей (никогда с таким не сталкивался), то можно сделать и переменный primary key.